# Setting up Database First EF Project Using Scaffold-DBContext

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database, and am trying to set-up a DB first EF project.  My project is a Web API project using .Net Core.  The command like I'm issuing is this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=Server\Instance;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.AppDomainOperationExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String startupAssembly, String projectDir, String contentRootPath, String dataDirectory, String rootNamespace, String environment)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.DbContextScaffoldCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The dependencies for this project are here:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "2.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-msbuild3-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "System.Collections.NonGeneric": "4.3.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.1.0"
  },
```

As you can see, it is referenced.

Please can someone point me in the right direction on this one?

EDIT:

Before it the current (complete) project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "2.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",    
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "System.Collections.NonGeneric": "4.3.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

With this configuration, I get a compilation error:

```
Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x86, win81-x86, win8-x86, win7-x86'. Possible causes:   JourneyService  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets  262 Build
```

Comment: Try my GUI wrapper: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/Release-notes

Comment: Delete `project.lock.json` and then try `dotnet restore`, may be this will help.

Comment: Makes no difference

Comment: May be `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design` is missing - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design/

Comment: It was indeed missing; however, adding it made no difference

Comment: Are you using project.json based project with msbuild based EF.Tools?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand the question (which may, in itself, answer your question).

Comment: Are you using the following package in your tools section? `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    }`.

Comment: @pm_2 can you update your question with complete `project.json`?

Comment: Still `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design'` error? If yes try to restore packages by `dontet restore`

Comment: Tried dotnet restore several times.  Tried bringing "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" in - this currently looks the most promising.  When I've sorted the version mismatches out, I will post the full project.json

Comment: I've updated the question with the complete project.json

Comment: You can use only `win10-x86, win81-x86, win8-x86, win7-x86` cuz you have only 32 bit version. Its impossible to convert 32 to 64bit. Change `runtime` to `win10-x86` and then try

Comment: If your OS is supporting x64 you can download and install 64-bit version of .Net from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current

Comment: What is the output from the command line when you run `dotnet --version`?

Comment: Output is: 1.0.0-rc4-004771

Comment: Following @Ahmar's comment, I seem to be stuck in this version of dot net.  I tried upgrading / changing but I seem to be stuck on this version.  Is there a new .Net Core way to update this?

Comment: @pm_2 I added detail steps in answer please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do the following steps.

1. Update your `.Net Core SDK` to most latest current version. (for new its `1.0.0-preview2-1-003177`). [download link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current)

[image]

2. Update `.Net Core SDK` version in `gobal.json` file
3. Update netcoreapp version in frameworks section of `project.json`

   ```
   "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
       ]
    }
   },
   ```
4. Add these packages to `project.json

   ```
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
     "version": "1.1.0",
     "type": "build"
   },
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
     "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
     "type": "build"
   }
   ```
5. Update your tools section in `project.json` and add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` latest version

   ```
   "tools": {
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
   },
   ```

Command:

```
`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=Server\\Instance;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models`
```

Complete `project.json` file.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "2.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "System.Collections.NonGeneric": "4.3.0",

    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: That gives me the following error: Scaffold-DbContext : The term 'Scaffold-DbContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.

Comment: delete your `project.lock.json` and then restore dependencies.
then try 'Scaffold-DbContext' command from `Package Manager console`.

Comment: I test this in my system and It worked. also check your dotnet SDK version with 'dotnet --version' command. It should be `1.0.0-preview2-1-003177`

Comment: @pm_2 I added detail steps in answer please check.

Comment: My project didn't have a global.json.  I tried creating it and specifying the SDK, but that made no difference, dotnet --version still shows `1.0.0-rc4-004771`

Comment: @pm_2 I added screen shot for `global.json` file in answer please check.